# Why is Android Studio opening many tabs of the link to Intellij IDEA when I open it?

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-23.10

I have since yesterday observed a strange behavior by Android Studio. Each time I open it, it opens the default browser and tries to open many tabs of this link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2023.1/getting-started.html . I can't work any more. I have also noticed that when I switch on my ubuntu 23.10.1 laptop it first bring the bios options telling me to click ENTER to proceed to start up. And when I do, it brings the lot of ^[[[A^[[[A^[[[A^ before bringing the login page. Why these two strange behaviors?. I have tried uninstalling android Studio and browsers both chrome and Firefox to no avail. Please help.